# Exclude files from angular environment

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am building an application that I install in different clients.
For this, I am using different enviroments, for example

environment.costumer1.ts
environment.costumer2.ts

The fact is that some customers use Services Workers and another does not, so I have created two different app.module.ts

```
app.module.ts
app.module-without-service-worker.ts
```

So, when a client asks me for an application without Service Worker (I use a notification service that I do not want to show who does not want it) I put it in angular.json, inside fileReplacements

```
{   
  "replace": "src / app / app.module.ts",
  "with": "src / app / app.module-without-service-worker.ts" 
}
```

The bad thing is that when doing a build of the main application I get the following error:

> ERROR in: Type AppComponent in D: / developments / Patient Portal /
>   patient-portal-demo / pp demo front / src / app / app.component.ts is
>   part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in D: / developments
>   / Patient Portal / patient-portal-demo / pp demo front / src / app /
>   app.module.ts and AppModule in D: / developments / Patient Portal /
>   patient-portal-demo / pp demo front / src / app / app.module-
>   without-service-worker.ts!

Is there a way to exclude files from an enviroment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a separate build for client1 and client2 then you can simply do the following things

Open the angular.json file and find the line

```
"serviceWorker": true
```

If you want to active service worker then the value is true else false.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This (and the other answers are similars) works perfect and of course is more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I found your post, when looking for answer for myself.

I tried your approach to load different components (and different routes config) based on build configuration, and it works for me.

Working in Angular 9.

Here is my angular.json:

```
"build": {
...
"configurations": {
   "custom": {
     "fileReplacements": [
       {
         "replace": "projects/my-app/src/app/app.module.ts",
         "with": "projects/my-app/src/app/app.module-custom.ts"
       }
     ]
   },
...
},
...
}
...
"serve": {
  ...
    "configurations": {
      ...
      "app": {
        "browserTarget": "rest-generator-app:build:custom"
      }
    }
  }
```

Then when I serve my app:

```
ng serve my-app --port=3000 -o --configuration=custom
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

Just define a flag within your environment properties.
See
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/

Answer (score 0):

An app should always have single entry point i.e. `AppModule`. So first you should never look a solution in building two separate `AppModule`.

If you problem is only limited to provide service worker based on environment then as @MoxxiManagarm said you can register a service worker in your app conditionally based on environment.

**To register service worker based on environment `app.module.ts`**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a property in the environment file.

**environmentx.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false;
  serviceWorker: false;
};
```

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.serviceWorker && environment.production})
],
```